# 2011 Mac Mini not working with included HDMI to DVI adapter

Tags: video, mac-mini, hdmi, video-adapter, dvi

I've got a [brand new Mac Mini](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC815LL/A) with a peculiar video issue.  It just won't show video using the [included](http://images.apple.com/macmini/images/techspecs_inthebox.jpg) HDMI to DVI adapter.:

- I've plugged this Mac Mini and adapter into three separate DVI monitors.  No video from any of them.
- The HDMI port works, and shows beautiful 1080p on my TV.
- The Thunderbolt port works on those aforementioned DVI monitors using a [Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA3Ng).
- I've tested the HDMI to DVI adapter alone (no Mac Mini involved) and it works great.

So the adapter works, the HDMI port works, the cable works, and the monitors work.  Just not together, for some reason.

Other voodoo attempted (unsuccessfully):

- Ran a full Software Update.  All updates have been downloaded and installed as of the time of this question.
- Put the Mac Mini to sleep, then woke it back up (using the Apple Remote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an unfortunate (but somewhat understandable, given the confusing nature of the issue) runaround from 1-800-APL-CARE, I managed to get a brand new HDMI to DVI adapter.

After extensive testing, it appears that the original HDMI to DVI adapter included with my Mac Mini works, with (seemingly) any device *except for my Mac Mini*.  The new HDMI to DVI adapter works great.  Must have been a very slight manufacturing defect in the original adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here with a Specter x20G Naga III monitor. A few days ago I tried to set up a new Mac mini for my wife. There was no video from the HDMI to DVI converter. I plugged the old Mac mini (circa 2007 but updated to Snow Leopard) in and the video worked just fine. I called Apple Care, they made an appointment with me at the Genius Bar, I took the new mini in and, using the same display adapter, it worked fine with their monitor. While installing the software updates at the Genius Bar, that mini kenel panicked. So they issued me a new one.

I brought the new mini home, plugged it in, and I had no video just like the first one. I tried a different DVI cable. No love. I tried another monitor with the HDMI to DVI converter and the video came through just fine. So I went back to the Apple store to pick up a mini display port to DVI converter. It didn't work on the Mac mini. It also did not work on my Macbook air.

My conclusion is that some DVI monitors just don't work with Lion. (Lion being the one commonality between my Macbook Air and my wife's Mac mini.) I ended up buying a new monitor. It works fine with the new Mac mini. I took the old monitor and set it up as a second display on my daughter's Mac mini which is still running Snow Leopard. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of would be a monitor detection issue when it's plugging in the HDMI to DVI-D adapter. I would see if you can plug in a second monitor via Thunderbolt, and try to detect the other display(s). Otherwise, this may be a job for 1(800)MY-APPLE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my new Mac Mini, went to the Apple store and they gave me a new DVI to HDMI adapter. I asked to have them test it before I left the store but they could not come up with a monitor with a DVI port. In the end they sold me a Belkin HDMI to DVI cable for one cent, just to have the goods transfer on record.

In my opinion, the store personnel did not know about the problem with the HDMI to DVI cable adapters, but after a few trips to the back room, they did the right thing without admitting that there is a problem. My monitor is a ViewSonic VP1201s (1600x1200) it is a few years old.

The "new" adapter that they gave me did not work either, but the Belkin was fine.